# Run/execute concatenated variable as command

Tags: bash, command

word2018 FILE_2018 > FILE_2018.out &

this works OK for me in bin/bash, terminal, konsole, BASH

I have an text-file script in #!/bin/bash, where I run this variable CMD and it works in CSH, but not in BASH.

```
CMD="word${year} ${FILE_version.txt} > ${FILE_version.out} &"

word2018 - system alias defined/sourced from other location
word - static name
2018 - variable (can be any number 2015, 2022,....)
FILE_version - variable (can be - FILE_2015, FILE_2022,...)

csh -c "$CMD" ...works OK
bash -c "$CMD" ...NOT working, command word2018 not found
```

any advice, help? I would appreciate very well

Comment: `alias_name = test` tries to run `alias_name` with `=` and `test` etc. as arguments, probably not what you want.

Comment: Trying to store commands in variables tends not to work very well (see [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and many previous questions here). Variables are really for storing data, not executable code. As for the example code in this question, it has so many problems it's hard to tell what're the real problems and what's just sloppy summarization.

Answer (score 1):

Just call $CMD

```
testABC(){
   echo "arg: $1"
}
alias_name=test
#....system alias
var1=ABC
var2=123

CMD="${alias_name}${var1} ${var2}"
echo CMD: $CMD

$CMD
```

result:

```
CMD: testABC 123
arg: 123
```

Comment: it doesnt work........

Comment: Works fine on Mint 20.3